# Mega Menu with vertical tabs onmouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, menu

I need to design mega menu similar to what is being used on this [website](http://www.hlgroup.com/en)..

My actual menus are dynamic and based on asp.net web form. I am not sure how actually i am going to implement it at this point. As a starting point i think of generating parent menu first and then logically rap sub-menus and jQuery vertical tabs and its contents in that menu wrapper.

May be image below can give a better idea.

[image]

At present i am not sure how i can wrap tabs for related menus under parent menu.

Second i want to change click event of tabs to hover even.

What i would love to do actually is to make it completely dynamic for which i need to make lot of changes to the database tables it self also.

I would appreciate if some could point me right direction for dynamic mega menu ...

for now i would like to start from basic. i have set up [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nn2Qw/1171/) and i am not sure how i can wrap tabs for each parent menu so that they will show up under the correct parent menu.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>
            <About us <ul>
                <li>Sub Menu 1</li>
                <li>Sub Menu 2</li>
                <li>Sub Menu 3</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Project
        <ul>
            <li>Project 1</li>
            <li>Project 2</li>
            <li>Project 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Media
        <ul>
            <li>Latest News</li>
            <li>Press Release</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Contact us</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Unfortunately their is not much for asp.net related asp.net mega menus. for PHP one can find much as it has lots of open source stuff & plugin available.

Mega menus are used on so many sites and one cant find much about the design consideration of these menus as a complete example. I wish some of the .net expert gurus can do an article which can address this issue which can act as a learning curve for many.

Comment: Ideally, your 'mega' menu contents should be semantically together. Practically though, you can put the contents anywhere in the page then visually assemble them together.